# Como se resuelve el error Parsing error: Missing semicolon?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando una barra de búsqueda que realiza la búsqueda llamando a una api, me encuentro con un error: Parsing error: Falta punto y coma. El error proviene de esta parte del código:
const form = event.target as HTMLFormElement.
específicamente entre el event.target y el as, e probado de poner ; pero no es correcto. ¿Podría alguien explicarme el motivo de este error y cómo solucionarlo?.///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import React, { FormEvent, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select, { SingleValue } from 'react-select'
import { getCollegiate } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import { Collegiate } from '@icofcv/common';
import Loader from '../spinner/Loader';


interface Props {
    showModal: boolean,
    closeModal: () => void
}


export const ModalFilterCollegiate: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModal, closeModal }) => {

    const [collegiateList, setCollegiateList] = useState<Collegiate[]>([]);
    const [collegiateSearch, setCollegiateSearch] = useState('');

    const searchForCollegiates = async (query: String): Promise<Collegiate[]> => {
        const result = await fetch(`/collegiate?filter=${query}`)
        return (await result.json()).results;
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const query = encodeURIComponent(collegiateSearch);
          const response = await searchForCollegiates(query);
          setCollegiateList(response);
        })();
      }, [collegiateSearch]);

      const search = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = event.target as HTMLFormElement;
        const input = form.querySelector('#searchText') as HTMLInputElement;
        setCollegiateSearch(input.value);
        input.value = '';
      };

    return (
        <>

            <div>
                {showModal ? (
                    <>
                        <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                            <div className="relative p-2 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
                                {/*content*/}
                                <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                                    {/*header*/}
                                    <div className="flex justify-between items-start px-4 py-3 rounded-t border-b">
                                        <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Buscar Colegiado</h3>
                                        <button className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center" onClick={closeModal}>
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    {/*body*/}
                                    <div className="relative px-3 py-3 flex-auto overflow-auto modal-body">                                    
                                         <form className="searchForm" onSubmit={event => search(event)} >
                                            <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-4">
                                                <div className="relative z-0 w-full group my-2">
                                                    <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Número colegiado</label>
                                                    <input name="" type="text" id="" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"/>
                                                    <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">Completa este espacio</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-4">
                                                <div className="relative z-0 w-full group my-2">
                                                    <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Nombre</label>
                                                    <input name="" type="text" id="searchText" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"/>
                                                    <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">Completa este espacio</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="relative z-0 w-full group my-2">
                                                    <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Apellidos</label>
                                                    <input name="" type="text" id="" className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"/>
                                                    <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">Completa este espacio</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-4">
                                                <div className="relative z-0 w-full group">
                                                    <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Provincia</label>
                                                    <select className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                                                        <option>Cualquier Provincia</option>
                                                     
                                                    </select>
                                                    <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">Completa este espacio</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="relative z-0 w-full group">
                                                    <label htmlFor="" className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600">Tipo</label>
                                                    <select className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                                                        <option>Seleccionar tipo</option>
                                                        <option>Ejercientes</option>
                                                        <option>No ejercientes</option>
                                                        <option>Honorarios</option>
                                                        <option>Colegiados de honor</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">Completa este espacio</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                                <div className="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-3 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b gap-2">
                                                    <button className="btn text-black text-sm background-transparent px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-600 focus:border-teal-600" type="button" onClick={closeModal}>Cancelar</button>
                                                    <button  className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white text-sm active:bg-teal-700 px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none" type="button">Buscar</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    {/*footer*/}
                                  
                                    { collegiateList.map((collegiate) => (
                                        <tr key={collegiate.id} className="bg-white border-b">
                                            <td className="py-2 px-6">
                                                {collegiate.color}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="py-2 px-6">
                                                {collegiate.collegiate}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="py-2 px-6">
                                                {collegiate.firstname}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="py-2 px-6">
                                                {collegiate.lastname}
                                            </td>
                                            <td className="py-2 px-6">
                                                {collegiate.provincia}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        ))
                                    }

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
                    </>
                ) : null}
            </div>


        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: En realidad el punto y coma te falta en esta otra línea: `const result = await fetch(`/collegiate?filter=${query}`)`

Comment: ¿Se elimina el error si eliminas el genérico en la declaración de tipo del parámetro de la función? Creo que Typescript se lía entre los <...> de React y los <...> que indican genéricos. Si es así, prueba a añadir una coma: `FormEvent<HTMLFormElement,>`

Comment: el erros sigue persistiendo

Comment: Si en el useEffect, en la linea `(async () => {` lo modificas a `;(async () => {`, persiste el error?